how to occupy the free space that remains after BottomNavigationView
activiti xml file:
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="JavaClassForActivity.Profile"
    android:id="@+id/ProfileLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/main_back_ground">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigation"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_parent"
                layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_music"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" />
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            android:background="@color/teal_700"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Java code:
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity{
    BottomNavigationView bottomnavigation;
private BottomSheetBehavior<View> bottomSheetBehavior;
    private LinearLayout layoutTop, layoutExpanded;
    int peekHeight;
    private View bottomSheet;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_profile);
        bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_parent);
        bottomnavigation=findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_parent);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

        layoutTop = findViewById(R.id.layout_top);
        layoutExpanded = findViewById(R.id.layout_expanded);

        // Setup the bottom sheet with initial peek height and behavior settings
        setupBottomSheet();

        // Set initial state
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}

    private void setupBottomSheet() {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = layoutTop.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                layoutTop.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                peekHeight = layoutTop.getHeight();
                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeight);
                bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
                bottomSheetBehavior.setFitToContents(true);
                return true;
            }
        });

        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                handleBottomSheetState(newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                handleSlideOffset(slideOffset);
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleBottomSheetState(int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            layoutTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutExpanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
            layoutTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutExpanded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED) {
            layoutTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutExpanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // Only set state to expanded if necessary
            if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleSlideOffset(float slideOffset) {
        float topAlpha = 1 - slideOffset;
        float expandedAlpha = slideOffset;
        layoutTop.setAlpha(topAlpha);
        layoutExpanded.setAlpha(expandedAlpha);
        if (layoutTop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !layoutTop.isActivated()) {
            layoutExpanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (layoutExpanded.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !layoutExpanded.isActivated()) {
            layoutTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        bottomnavigation.setTranslationY(bottomnavigation.getHeight() * slideOffset);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = bottomSheet.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = bottomSheet.getHeight() + (int) (bottomnavigation.getHeight() * slideOffset);
        bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}

bottom_sheet_music xml file:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">`


</LinearLayout>

<!-- layout_expanded -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_expanded"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/black">
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I don't know how to solve it, if you can show me an example of how to solve the problem, I would appreciate it.
I tried different options I found and couldn't solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Update:
I found a partial solution to my problem.
Here is the updated code of the handleSlideOffset method:
private void handleSlideOffset(float slideOffset) {
        float topAlpha = 1 - slideOffset;
        float expandedAlpha = slideOffset;
        layoutTop.setAlpha(topAlpha);
        layoutExpanded.setAlpha(expandedAlpha);
        if (layoutTop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !layoutTop.isActivated()) {
            layoutExpanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (layoutExpanded.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !layoutExpanded.isActivated()) {
            layoutTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (slideOffset >= previousSlideOffset) {
            float translationY = bottomnavigation.getHeight() * slideOffset;
            Log.e("translationY",String.copyValueOf(String.valueOf(translationY).toCharArray()));
            float scale = 1 - slideOffset;
            Log.e("scale",String.copyValueOf(String.valueOf(scale).toCharArray()));
            bottomnavigation.setTranslationY(translationY);
            bottomnavigation.setScaleX(scale);
            bottomnavigation.setScaleY(scale);    
            
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = bottomnavigation.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = (int) (bottomnavigation.getHeight() * scale);
            Log.e("params.height",String.copyValueOf(String.valueOf(params.height).toCharArray()));
            bottomnavigation.setLayoutParams(params);    
           
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams bottomSheetParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) bottomSheet.getLayoutParams();
            int bottomNavigationHeight = bottomnavigation.getHeight();
            Log.e("bottomSheetParams",String.copyValueOf(bottomSheetParams.toString().toCharArray()));
            bottomSheetParams.height = (int) (bottomSheet.getHeight() + bottomNavigationHeight - (bottomNavigationHeight * slideOffset));
            Log.e("bottomSheetParams.height",String.copyValueOf(String.valueOf(bottomSheetParams.height).toCharArray()));
            bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(bottomSheetParams);
            previousSlideOffset=slideOffset;
        }
        else {
           //I don't know how to bring it back smoothly and also in stages(
        }
    }

activity xml:
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="JavaClassForActivity.Profile"
    android:id="@+id/ProfileLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/main_back_ground">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationContainer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationContainer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_parent"
                layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_music"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" />
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
                android:background="@color/teal_700" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Update video:


I had the same problem but for me using some layer with required color behind of BottomNavigation solved it

Thanks for the answer, but this solution to the problem is not suitable unfortunately.
